mysql-connector-python error No module named 'mysql.connector.plugins.mysql_native_password'
I am using Mysql server: 10.5.19-MariaDB-0+deb11u2
installed mysql-connector-python, tried many versions from 8.1 to 9+
When my python code reaches the line mysql.connector.connect()the below exception happens:
I have tried to alter the mysql user to chaching-sha2-password by could not do that, some documents say that my db server does not support it.
Requested Module was not found: No module nam ed 'mysql.connector.plugins.mysql_native_password'
Process Process-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
  File "multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
  File "SQL_MY.py", line 326, in sql_process_launcer
    my_sql_proc_object=sql_process(process_communicator)
  File "SQL_MY.py", line 338, in __init__
    self.db_con=connect_to_db()
  File "SQL_MY.py", line 13, in connect_to_db
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  File "mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 294, in connect
  File "mysql/connector/connection.py", line 172, in __init__
  File "mysql/connector/connection.py", line 636, in close
  File "mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1155, in cmd_quit
  File "mysql/connector/network.py", line 604, in send
  File "mysql/connector/network.py", line 221, in send
  File "mysql/connector/network.py", line 167, in _send_pkt
  File "mysql/connector/errors.py", line 54, in __init__
  File "mysql/connector/locales/__init__.py", line 62, in get_client_error
ImportError: No localization support for language 'eng'


Note: issue resolved after installing mysql-connector-python version 8.0.11, anyone has a better recommendation?
